# Android Studio Javadoc errors

Tags: java, android, javadoc, r.java-file

When working within Android Studio, I cannot generate a javadoc. When I try, it comes up with around 100 errors complaining of "unknown" things. I haven't touched these files before and mainly are associated with the R.java file.

Here's the console output for you all to examine: https://gist.github.com/DXC0/6e05231d704001111207

**EDIT:**
Some stuff *does* generate, but it's weird that there are so many errors. I made sure to download the documentation and add it as a reference.

Comment: Hey, I am facing same stuff. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Afraid not. Just ignore the errors because the relevant documentation is generated.